# Separate .tiff stack into two files according to difference in mean pixel value in python

Tags: python, image-processing, tiff

I am working on a program for analysis of .tiffs of fluorescent microscopy images; detection of regions of interest and saving them into memory. However, the program keeps running into problems with duplicate registration of regions of interest, for the random position changes of in-vivo microscope are far too big for any kind of motion correction to properly handle (= camera shakes like hell, preventing proper roi detection).

Is there a way in Python of loading a greyscale .tiff stack, detecting mean pixel value difference between frames and separating the .tiff into two files according to certain (considered 'large-enough') change of mean pixel value between frames?

Edit: Is there a nice a way of calculating a mean difference of grey values in between frames of tiff stored as numpy array and separating this array into two?

This would allow the program to automatically chop the tiff file into more or less stable pieces which could be analysed for regions of interest separately and compared post-hoc for elimination of duplicates.

Thank you for your answer,
JJ

Now here I would like to have something which is able to take my array and figure out mean grey value change in various snapshots of the image; but I don't quite now how I would like to go about it, and upon detection of certain value of change, cuts out all of the preceeding frames and exports them as seperate tiff, continuing to do this as many times as necessary (to cover up for major movements) until I don't have multitude of arrays, every one of them a more-or-less stable set of frames and then just simple exporting via Image.fromarray(imarray)

sample image can be found here:
http://www.filedropper.com/frames_1

(this is a version of image which already went through pretty hardcore 2d translation and rotation motion correct function, original is much more shaky), around frame 300 the whole thing just shifts to the right. The objective is to automatically generate one .tiff which would encompass frames app. 1-300 (before the 'big shift') and a second .tiff for the rest of the sequence. Subsequent analysis of pictures would then identify regions of interest (pale dots) in every one of the two newly generated tiffs, avoiding accidental duplication caused by shift of FOV and allowing for capturing of all regions of interest found in the recording.

Edited by Mark Setchell

I did some basic contrast adjustments and made your 443 frames into an animated GIF:

[image]

Edit3: So after lots of thinking, I came to conclusion that what I need to do is to force numpy to provide me with a sum of first 138000 values which will correspond to first frame (for img size of 400x345) and then calculate delta of those in comparison with next 138000 values. But how to access the second slide of my .tiff file? How does PIL store the whole tiff and how it operates with it, frame by frame?

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('example_recording.tif').convert('LA')
im.save('greyscale_example.tif')
im.show()

width,height = im.size

total_a=0
for i in range(0,width):
    for j in range(0,height):
        total_a += im.getpixel((i,j))[0]

print total_a
```

This comes up with what I believe is my overall gray value. I would like to compare it with grey value of following frame like this:

```
 Mean_difference_ab = total_a - total b
 abs(Mean_difference_ab)
```

and compare it against a threshold which I would figure out experimentally... But I still don't know how to extract the data from slides following the first.

Comment: Not much of code as of now for that part; see edit

Comment: Could you upload a zip of some sample images somewhere? It's not clear how bad the problem is, or what types of change you are seeing between frames.

Comment: problem is pretty bad, and further motion correct is not acceptable as it will eliminate the junctions seen in the second part of recording; type of change should be expressible in very high delta of mean grey values of the frames in comparison to preceding. If you want, have a look